shell command for automatically opening a Git unmerged files in VSCode
So I'll admit I don't know much about Shell as I am just learning Git. However, my textbook is proving a point that you can use shell in your git commands and I am curious on how to do so (for when I use shell in the future).
Take a look at the following git configuration.
[alias]
editconflicted = "!f() {git ls-files --unmerged | cut -f2 | sort -u; }; $EDITOR 'f'"
[core]
editor = code --wait

Keep in mind that I am using Windows, and I know the double quotations and how parsing happens can change from one OS to another OS. Even though I tried playing around with the quotations for editconflicted, I still got this error.
f() {git ls-files --unmerged | cut -f2 | sort -u; }; $EDITOR f;: -c: line 1: syntax error near unexpected token `{git'
f() {git ls-files --unmerged | cut -f2 | sort -u; }; $EDITOR f;: -c: line 1: `f() {git ls-files --unmerged | cut -f2 | sort -u; }; $EDITOR f;'

If anyone can provide the command on how VSCode can automatically open unmerged files when I try to merge 2 branches, then that would be great.

I think what you are actually looking for is setting vscode up as your mergetool. https://www.roboleary.net/vscode/2020/09/15/vscode-git.html
